# check if an email address is valid in an asp.net mvc view with razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My task is to make an application that:

- parses a .CSV (comma separated values) file.
- Displays the values
- exclude values that contain invalid email addresses

Is it possible to do this purely in the view?  Code for my best attempt at the view is below.  However, I keep getting the following error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition
>   for 'includes' and no extension method 'includes' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;

<h2>Upload File</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

    if (Model != null)
    {
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {   
                    var email = row["Email"];

                    <tr >
                        @if (email.includes("@")) {
                        foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {

                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }

                        }
                    </tr>


                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Comment: tell me what you mean by invalid? not in email format?

Comment: @Valkyriee yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: The compiler thinks `email` is type object which does not have a method `.includes()`. You'll need casting or some kind of conversion.

Comment: Is it possible to do in a View? Sure. Probably not a good idea. [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is an important point to keep in mind when programming. Even for a simple program, it's not good to shoehorn things where they shouldn't be. Additionally, I'd steer clear of using a `DataTable` as the model in your view. Use strongly typed objects. It makes the view cleaner and reduces the likelihood of mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, limiting the dataset is more of the responsibility of the controller, rather than the view.

That being said, there are a few ways I'm aware of to validate an email address. The first of which is to use the [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx) class constructor, which will throw a `FormatException` should the email address not be of a valid format:

```
string email = row["Email"].ToString();
try {
    var address = new MailAddress(email);
    // Do something with the valid email address.
}
catch(FormatException ex){
    // The email address was invalid.
}
```

Note: If you expect many of the addresses to be invalid, the overhead of throwing and catching the exception may take a hit to your performance.

Another option is to use `Regex.IsMatch(email, someRegexString)` to determine whether or not the email matches some regular expression. Depending how generic or simple your email address rules are, you may be able to find some options for what `someRegexString` could look like by searching around online. If your rules are simple enough, it may be easiest to try and [build your own](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

If looking for the presence of the `@` character is good enough, you can use `Contains()`:

```
string email = row["Email"].ToString();
@if (email.Contains("@")) {
    <tr>
    foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
    {
        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @Jf2k`test@@example.com` is a valid email address according to the algorithm posted. So is `@example.com` or `examplecom@`. That isn't correct. Keep in mind for parsing common formats, you're far better off using something prebuilt, you'll get it wrong if you roll your own. Even something as simple as an email address can be surprisingly complex.